# Excel crashing launching macros after closing userform

Tags: excel, vba, crash, userform

Good Morning.

After closing a userform excel crash when I start a macro.
Macros, before open userform, works very well.
I try to add the following code, but excel still crashing.

```
...
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
Unload Me
ThisWorkbook.Application.Caption
Sheets(“MySheet”).Activate
End Sub
...
```

Thanks

---

Now I delete the Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()

My macro, launched from button is:

```
Public Sub CercaNazione()
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
Dim MyInput As String
Dim filtro As Range
Set filtro = ActiveSheet.Range(“Nation”)
MyInput = InputBox(“Filter Nation”, "Filter Nation", “Insert Nation”)
If MyInput = "Insert Nation" Or MyInput = "" Then
   Exit Sub
End If
filtro.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*" & MyInput & "*"
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select ‘A1 = header
End Sub
```

The macro works very well, but after opening/closing my Userform, clicking on button excel close suddenly.

Comment: "Crashing" as in just closing down, or is there an error message you can share?

Comment: Excel close suddenly. I've only Error Log: Microsoft Error Reporting log version: 2.0
Error Signature:
Exception: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
ExceptionEnumString: 2
Exception Code: 0x00000001 (0x0000600003e67000)
Date/Time: 2023-05-16 09:54:58 +0000
Application Name: Microsoft Excel
Application Bundle ID: com.microsoft.Excel
Application Signature: XCEL......

Comment: 1) The UserForm_Terminate fired after call the> Unload any_form_object. So the command Unload in the UserForm_Terminate is useless  2) What is the:  ThisWorkbook.Application.Caption ? Have to Set a value or to read the value. 3) As i coment to fire the UserForm_Terminate somewhere you call an Unload... I think is better to put the commands in that Sub or Function.